# How to use the vscode python debugger with a project built with bazel?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, bazel, vscode-debugger

I want to debug a python file which has a few dependencies that only appear in the `runfiles` from bazel. How can I debug a bazel build with the vscode debugger?

Comment: Did you find an answer in the meantime? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I actually have, let me reply as an answer (and sorry for forgetting to reply here!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As someone famous said, "Yes, we can".

You would need to use the "ptvsd" python package.

### One-time Setup

- Add "ptvsd" as a Python dependency in Bazel
- In VS Code, in your `launch.json` file, add the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 5724,
    "host": "localhost"
},
```

### Debug

When you want to debug a specific file:

- In the Python file you want to debug, add the following lines:

```py
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('localhost', 5724), redirect_output=True)
print('Now is a good time to attach your debugger: Run: Python: Attach')
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

- Run Bazel on this file as you normally would (`bazel run :server` for instance)
- Execution will stop at "Now is a good time to attach your debugger: Run: Python: Attach"
- In VS Code, click on the "Python: Attach" debug option that we setup earlier:

[image: Python attach button]

- That's it!

Feel free to change the port, 5724 in this example.

Answer (score 5):

`ptvsd` is [deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd#-%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%A0s%E1%B4%85-%C9%AAs-%E1%B4%85%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%98%CA%80%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%84%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85-), replaced by [`debugpy`](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/).

Usage is the same as the accepted answer, except that the code snippet for the Python file has changed:

```py
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(5678)
debugpy.wait_for_client()  # blocks execution until client is attached
```