# How to let VS Code discover Bazel tests?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, bazel

When opening a Bazel project in VS Code, it does not automatically discover the Bazel tests in the test runner, even with the bazel plugin installed.

I had to run tests using terminal commands.

Is there a way to run Bazel tests in the VS Code test runner?

Comment: The official bazel plugin for vscode will discover tests, but it will insert a little link above the test target to run the test. It won't run them all at once though. I'd recommend getting comfortable using the command line. It's incredibly powerful and you'll learn a lot more that way :) If you don't want to keep running the command line, consider looking at google/bazel-watcher.

Comment: There is already a visual studio bazel [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BazelBuild.vscode-bazel) , but am not sure that has support to recognise the test cases under your project structure directory.  To work may be you can use below [IDE's](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/ide.html) which are more powerful than VS at present.

Comment: What language are you trying to run tests for? The answer varies based on language. E.g., it's apparently possible in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334688/how-to-use-the-vscode-python-debugger-with-a-project-built-with-bazel. Same with C++: https://web.archive.org/web/20220814063837/https://shanee.io/blog/2019/05/28/bazel-with-visual-studio-code/. With Go, it seems less possible: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/1844